# How do I fix this attribute error python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributeerror

I'm having a problem with my code. I'm trying to extract the listed jobs on this website (https://www.local.ch/en/q/geneve/employment%20agency?slot=yellow) with the names of the Company and the link to their information. The first part works, I am able to print all the names but then printing the link to its information gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    href = (links.get("href"))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 921, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is my code:

```
print("Hello, welcome to local job in geneva finder")

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.local.ch/en/q/geneve/employment%20agency?slot=yellow"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
names = soup.findAll("h2")
for name in names:
    print(name.text)

link = soup.find("a")
for links in link:
    href = (links.get("href"))
    if href.startswith("https://www.local.ch/en/d/geneve/1204/recruiting"):
        print(href)
```

Comment: `for links in name:` - should that be `for links in link:`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `findAll` to extract all `<a>` tags.

```
links = soup.findAll("a")
```

Iterate the loop for links instead of names to get `href` from all `<a>` tags. 
`link.get("href")` can return None too incase of href not found in `<a>` tag. So write a condition for checking weather its None or not.

Complete Code:

```
print("Hello, welcome to local job in geneva finder")
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.local.ch/en/q/geneve/employment%20agency?slot=yellow"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
names = soup.findAll("h2")
for name in names:
    print(name.text)

links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    href = link.get("href")
    if href:
        if href.startswith("https://www.local.ch/en/d/geneve/1204/recruiting"):
            print(href)
```

Comment: I am trying to print the link to further information on all of the jobs listed. When I run the program it only shows the link first job listed.

Comment: Didn't get your point.. Do you want to extract information from all pages? then use pagination. Change the link for every page using loop...

Comment: I want to take the name of each of the jobs listed on the website with the link to each of the jobs listed